# Can I extend Jira Agile with a plugin to add a new panel, like "Versions" and "Epics"?

Tags: agile, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I would like to extend Jira Agile to add a new panel. You know, like the built in filter panels on the left of a boards plan view "Epics" and "Versions". A panel to allow filtering and summarizing on topics other than Epics and Versions.

I've worked through the tutorials for general plugin development. Downloaded the greenhopper source code for inspiration, but cannot see where to start. 
Thank you for any pointers you can give.

Comment: have you found a solution? I would like to do this too